# Auto Bcc using amavis

Tags: amavis

I have installed amavisd-new ,spamassissin , postfix server. I want to implement  the autobcc  feature using amavisd. so please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

Postfix has a always_bcc setting, which you might want to use or look into.